# Should my customers purchase an API plan if I am a partner?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a simple question. We are a CRM and are integrating with Docusign. So, whenever our customers want to send an envelope, they can send it from the CRM.

Do our customers have to purchase a separate API plan with Docusign?
From what I have read through, that is not the case but API limit of 1000 API calls per hour apply.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related question

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to talk to your Account Manager for specific recommendations, or the Sales team if you don't have one.

As a general matter, you would need to own an API plan as the integration's owner but your customers could use your integration on any DocuSign account that has the appropriate level of features/functionality.

Comment: As a DocuSign ISV / partner you only need an API plan to send test envelopes on the production system and to manage your Integration key's settings. Your customers will use their own DocuSign accounts to send envelopes via your integration as Drew indicates in his answer.